# Webservice c# free database

Tags: c#, database, web-services

I want to learn webservice development using c# and a free database. Could someone tell me what is the best free database solution to work with c#?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While learning, just stick to the visual studio ide and utilize the integration with iis and sql express which should be already installed. web services in C# need iis (due to .net framework requirement for c#) plus the visual studio ide is easyily integrated with sql express. after you get some learning in, you can move towards installing and connecting to other databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL ect..

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft have a free version of their SQL Server database which is [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/). Also they recently released a new [Embedded Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx) which is worth checking out. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) are other popular choices.

As far as web service development in .NET is concerned [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) is the recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

There is also sql express and sql ce

Answer (score 0):

I use MySQL with c# and Entity Framework every day.  It works great, and you won't be limited by the express edition of SQL Server that way.